# crystal if statement error

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports

I am having trouble with an If statement in crystal reports. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong

```
if (time > -1) then
    prev = time
else if (isnull({tbl.field}))then //error on this line
    prev := 0
else
    prev := TONUMBER({tbl.field});
```

It is giving me a "Boolean expected here error" on the second if after the else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if time > -1 then
    prev := time  // missing :
else if isnull({tbl.field}) then
    prev := 0
else
    prev := TONUMBER({tbl.field})
;
```

Comment: Thanks i have been staring at this for 30 minutes trying to find that